# what is the efficient way of implementing CholeskySolve in eigen without using intermediate matrices or buffers?

Tags: matrix, eigen

I tried as follows

```
l = l.triangularView<Lower>();
x1 = (l*l.transpose()).llt().solve(y1);
```

where l,y1 are input matrices and x1 output matrix.Output came as expected,but in this case the l matrix changes after execution of first statement.
I don't want to change the l matrix.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: It is unclear to me why you need `llt()` when you already have the decomp result `l`

Answer (score 1):

You already have a LLT factorization, so simply apply `l`'s inverse twice:

```
x = l.triangularView<Lower>().solve(y);
x = l.triangularView<Lower>().transpose().solve(x);
```

No temporary, everything will be performed in-place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
(MatrixXf::Identity(l.rows(), l.cols()) * 
    l.triangularView<Lower>() * l.triangularView<Upper>())
```

Ugly, but for some reason `l.triangularView<Lower>() * l.triangularView<Upper>()` doesn't work (binary `operator*` doesn't take a left-hand type of `TriangularView`, at least not with Eigen 3.2.8).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Cholesky decomposition, as the lower triangular matrix `l.triangularView<Lower>()` is the decomposition result.

To calculate `x1` from `l` and `y1` you only need to solve two triangular equations.

```
x1 = l.triangularView<Lower>().conjugate().transpose().solve(
         l.triangularView<Lower>().solve(y1)
     );
```